# Stream a recoreded Video to youtube

Tags: video, youtube, stream

I have a video local already recoreded and i want to stream it to my youtube channel as a live Stream not as an Uploaded Video.

I found a website to do this https://scheduler.restream.io/ but it cost alot to do it.

I there is any tool for Ubuntu to make this possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **Encoder streaming** (one of the three live streaming "options" [listed by YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/howyoutubeworks/product-features/live/)).
See also [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2907883?ref_topic=9257984&visit_id=637361091274699746-7516424&rd=1).

[This](https://linuxforever.info/2017/05/06/how-to-live-stream-to-youtube-from-linux-mint-ubuntu/) provides detailed instructions on how to do that in Linux Mint with `ffmpeg`, but they should work flawlessly in Ubuntu.
Please try them and post feedback.
I will start posting them here for future reference.

Note [this interesting post](https://akhromieiev.com/tutorials/how-to-broadcast-any-radio-station-to-youtube-using-ffmpeg/) which does essentially the same, but using another URL as the source, instead of your local video file.

Comment: i think this is what i'm looking for, I'v used ops before but i thought in my case it would be better to use another took, anyway i installed it and i would test now i got another problem on youtube because ii'v made no live streams before i need to wait 24 hours till they active the live streaming for me. I will get in touch with you if this will work.

Comment: It woks perfect, thank alot

Comment: @TonGok - Glad it worked.